# assigning variable prior to elif statement

Tags: python, if-statement

this might be very basic but I am not getting any clue

*my code is something like this:*

```
for tickers in ticklist:
  if function_1(x,y) is True:
     do task1
  elif function_2(x,y) is True:
     do task1
  elif function_3(x,y) > a and function_3(x,y) < b:
     do task1
  else:
     do task2
```

I know that this code is equivalent to having:

```
for tickers in ticklist:
  if function_1(x,y) is True or function_2(x,y) is True or function_3(x,y) > a and 
  function_3(x,y) < b:
     do task1
  else:
     do task2
```

The reason for breaking into multiple lines is to prevent the unwanted condition check and save loop time because each function here represents an api call (which takes quite a bit of time). So, my goal is to end the loop once one condition is True. However, in the third condition the same function is called twice (which means calling api twice).

```
...
elif function_3(x,y) > a and function_3(x,y) < b:
     do task1
```

Is there a way to assign the return of a function to a variable before entering into elif so that the condition can be checked with the assigned variable rather than going to the function twice.

something like:

```
...
elif var = function_3(x,y) 
    if var> a and var < b:
     do task1
```

Comment: Hello! You can use something like this: `elif a < function_3(x,y) < b:`

Comment: Where do you see an unwanted condition check? Just use `if function_1(x,y) or function_2(x,y) or a < function_3(x,y) < b`. `or` stops evaluating if it finds the first true value.

Comment: Your multiple `elif` statements are not an optimization at all; `if a() or b()` will not examine `b()` if `a()` is truthy.

Comment: conditions short circuit, so if you have something like `if A or B or C` and A evaluates true, then B and C won't even be evaluated. No need to break the condition into `if... elif`

Comment: About the _actual_ question: If comparison chaining is not possible, you could use the `:=` assignment-within-an-expression operator: `elif (tmp := function_3(x,y)) > a and some_other_test(tmp):`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like:

```
if func_1(x,y):
  Task 1
elif func_2(x,y):
  Task 1
else:
  n = func_3(x,y)
  if n>a and n<b:
    Task 1
  else:
    Task 2
```

would work for you.